# Creating a simulated HLS live stream from multiple MP4 sources with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, live, http-live-streaming

I've already tried to create HLS stream from a UDP continuous input stream, it was fairly easy, now I want to create a simulated live HLS stream from multiple MP4 sources with ffmpeg, the idea behind it is to be able to create a TV channel with non-live data, so the input must be a loop of non-live data to simulate live stream continuity. I tried to do it with the below command but after the first round, ffmpeg exits with this error:

```
concat:1.mp4|2.mp4|3.mp4" Resource temporarily unavailable.
```

ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:1.mp4|2.mp4|3.mp4" -strict experimental -sn  -ac  2  -map_metadata  -1  -s  720x576  -g  250  -c:v  libx264  -pix_fmt  yuv420p  -flags  -global_header  -hls_time  10  -hls_list_size  5  -hls_wrap  12  -hls_flags  delete_segments  -f  hls  -strftime  1  -segment_time  10  -segment_format  mpegts  -segment_list_flags  +live  -hls_allow_cache  0  -segment_wrap  12  -segment_list_size  5  -hls_base_url  http://192.168.1.100/0/  -hls_segment_filename  /data/0/live_0_%02d.ts  /data/0/live_0.m3u8
```

If anyone has a nice solution to this issue, I would appreciate any input.

Cheers,
Navid

Comment: Either rewrap the MP4s as TS or use the concat demuxer.

Comment: I was able to get the stream to work but its not live -- it basically just encodes all the movies into one giant .ts file that starts at the beginning for each user....I am not sure how to concat + do a live stream.

Comment: Need to get done something along similar lines of what you were trying @chovy. Were you able to figure out a way to concat or even serve 1 mp4 as a simulated live stream ? I too was able to generate the m3u8 playlist here - http://cdn.urtutors.com.storage.googleapis.com/concept_video_1/test1.m3u8 but it is not live just encoded only. Can you please help out in getting this done ?